# How to iterate over array of some protocol that conform to View protocol?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My goal is to create SomeProtocol that confroms View protocol and then use this to create array of SomeProtocol with ForEach loop and use body from every SomeProtocol.

Currently i have something like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: View, Identifable {
    var name: String { get }
}

public struct ActualView: View {

let items: [SomeProtocol]
// Error: Protocol 'SomeProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

init(items: [SomeProtocol]) {
    self.items = items
}

public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(items) { item in
        // Error: Value of protocol type 'SomeProtocol' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
            Text(item.name)
            // Member 'body' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'SomeProtocol'; use a generic constraint instead
            item.body
        }
    }
}
```

In shorter version i want to pass some view throught protocol but add some additional infomrations to it.

Comment: You will end up with AnyView... actually it is opposite to SwiftUI concept, so I'd not recommend this way. Model is model, view is view... don't mess them up.

Comment: Could you explain me how to use AnyView and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `ActualView` generic, like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: View, Identifiable {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ActualView<Item: SomeProtocol>: View {
    let items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                item
            }
        }
    }
}
```